# Should I only render state variables in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a render method, is it bad practice to render class variables?

```
return (<span>{this.value}</span>);
```

Or should it always be state variables:

```
return (<span>{this.state.value}</span>);
```

Comment: Would depend if `this.value` would ever change. If it does better to put it in state for react to observe changes

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633145/react-es6-component-variables-in-construct-vs-state-variables

Answer (score 0):

My experience says that if your view depends on the variable and your component should react and update the view if this variable changes then you MUST use state variable. because any change to the state will trigger your re-render and reconciliation will update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a distinction whether you want to flush the changes to UI whenever you are changing the
value of the variable.

Its better to minimize the state variables as number of re-renders would be lesser.